# Multiple On-click Events HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, buttonclick, spring-expression-language

I'm simply trying to create an HTML button that has two `onclick` events, but the issue is that the second one is not responding properly. Here is the button tag below:

```
<input class="btn btn-default btn-responsive" type="button" onclick="return confirm('Cancel Changes?'); location.href='${cancelLink}'" value="Cancel Changes"/>
```

I must be doing something incorrectly due to the expression language in location.href, but I'm not sure what it is since I'm very unfamiliar with using expression language in these instances.  I do know that this link is working though, because if I use it in an 'a' tag with an `href=${cancelLink}`, it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have multiple onclick events unless you click the button multiple times.

You have one click event listener which has two statements in it.

This is the function you are using:

```
function () {
    return confirm('Cancel Changes?');
    location.href='${cancelLink}'
}
```

The first line has a `return` statement in it, so you **never** reach the second line.

If you want to conditionally do something, then use an **if** statement, not a return statement:

```
function () {
    if (confirm('Cancel Changes?')) {
        location.href='${cancelLink}'
    }
}
```

However, all you are doing here is using JavaScript to simulate a regular link: So you should use a regular link:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-responsive" 
   onclick="return !confirm('Cancel Changes?')"
   href="${cancelLink}">
       Cancel Changes
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

<input class="btn btn-default btn-responsive" type="button" onclick="Click()" value="Cancel Changes"/>

<script>
    
    
    function Click(){ confirm("cancel changes"); }
    

</script>

</body>
```

Function should be written sperately in JavaScript tag